# How to extend a WCF Data Services context class on clientside?

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

I'm using the following code to extend my Service-Context with a FullName on clientside:

```
public partial class Customer {
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Concat(LastName, (FirstName == "" ? "" : ", "), FirstName);
        }
    }
}
```

That works fine, until it comes to the point where I need to Add a new Object to the Context with the AddOBject Method. It throws an Exception. When I remove the FullName extension th AddObject method saves the new Object to the database. 
What is the best way to extend my Context and still make it Update- and Insertable?

**Edit:** The DataServiceRequest Exception:

```
System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequestException was not handled by user code.
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Fehler beim Verarbeiten dieser Anforderung.
  Source=Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.WindowsStore
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Services.Client.SaveResult.HandleResponse()
       at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseSaveResult.EndRequest()
       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.EndSaveChanges(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at Pointsale.Client.Service.PointsaleEntities.<SaveChanges>b__0(IAsyncResult asResult) in c:\Users\Jan\Desktop\pointsale_worksapce\pointsale.client\Helper\TenantHelper.cs:line 98
       at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
  InnerException: System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code /><m:message xml:lang="de-DE">Error occurred while processing this request.</m:message></m:error>
       StatusCode=400
       InnerException:
```

And the SaveChanges method overide to get it async:

```
public async Task<DataServiceResponse> SaveChanges()
{
    var queryTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync(this.BeginSaveChanges(null, null), asResult =>
    {

        var result = this.EndSaveChanges(asResult);
        return result;

    });
    return await queryTask;
}
```

On EndSaveChanges the error occures.

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace from the exception? Or, conversely, just the message itself would be helpful if you can't get that.

Comment: @ MikeReed - MSFT: I updated my question.

Comment: From that stack trace it looks like we're running into an error serverside while trying to run the update operation. Next step would be to take a look at what's going over the wire between the client and server to see what's screwed up in the request. I would try running Fiddler http://fiddler2.com/home to capture the request payload in both the positive and negative cases and see that the difference is, then we can go from there!

Comment: Look at this link to find out how to get more information from the server about what exactly went wrong -http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx. My guess would be that the client is sending this property on the wire and server is failing since it does not know about this property.

Comment: That seems to e the problem. I found [that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/12/11/customizing-serialization-of-entities-in-the-ado-net-data-services-client-library.aspx) workaround using a [DoNotSeralize] attribute. Wondering why this isn't allready included into EF...